# Keep line below menu when expanding

Tags: drop-down-menu, styling

I have a line below menu items when hovered.
It is a drop down menu, and i want to keep the line when i hover in the submenus.

Here is my code:

```
    <nav id="primary_navigation">
<h1>Primary Navigation Menu</h1>
<ul>
<li class="active"><a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about-us/">About Us</a></li>
<li class="has-sub"><a href=""><span>Services</span></a>
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><span>Service 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>Service 2</span></a></li>
    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Fees and Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </nav>
```

Here is CSS:

```
nav#primary_navigation h1{
display: none;
text-align: center; 
}
nav#primary_navigation {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 100px;
font-family: 'Eraslght';
font-size: 18pt;
line-height: 20pt;
}
nav#primary_navigation ul {
list-style:none;

}
nav#primary_navigation ul li {
display: block;
float: left;
position: relative;
margin-left: 25px;


}
nav#primary_navigation ul li a:link, nav#primary_navigation ul li a:visited {
display: block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
/*1*/
nav#primary_navigation ul li:hover a{ 
display: block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;  
color: black;

}
nav#primary_navigation ul li a:hover, nav#primary_navigation ul li a:visited{
display: block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: solid #000000;   
} 

nav#primary_navigation ul li a:active {
display: block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;   

}
/*fin 1*/
nav#primary_navigation ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
background-color: #04E1BE;
}
nav#primary_navigation ul li ul {
margin: 0px;
list-style: none;
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: -2px;
}
nav#primary_navigation ul li ul li {    
width: 100px;
clear: left;
margin-left: -5px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
nav#primary_navigation ul li ul li a:link{
clear:left;
padding:4px 0px 0px 4px;
border:none;
position:relative;
z-index:1000;
}
nav#primary_navigation ul li ul li:hover a, nav#primary_navigation ul li ul li a:active, nav#primary_navigation ul li ul li a:hover {
clear:left;
color: white;
padding:4px 0px 0px 4px;
border:none;
position:relative;
z-index:1000;
}
```

Can anyone tell me a hint? i cant see where i should code what.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ or an image or more information about the problem itself

Answer (score 0):

As i have seen through it. You have given that `padding-bottom` property to `li a:hover` or visited or active, whatever but you have nested your submenus in the `li` element, So how can it be possible, bro? you are ending that element `nav#primary_navigation ul li a` before starting the submenus `ul li` because

```
<li class="has-sub"><a href=""><span>Services</span></a> [your li a ends here]
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><span>Service 1</span></a></li> [So here no hover action'll be applied] here
    <li><a href=""><span>Service 2</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So, just use style like this.

```
nav#primary_navigation ul li:hover, nav#primary_navigation ul li:visited{
display: block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: solid #000000;   
}
```

instead

```
nav#primary_navigation ul li a:hover, nav#primary_navigation ul li a:visited{
/*style goes here*/   
}
```

Hope you get it.